# create dataframes with different names with pd. read_csv and for loop

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import os
path=r"C:\Users\berid\OneDrive\Desktop\mydata\covid19 South Korea\\"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    print(file)
```

output:

[image]

I want to create dataframes with the same names as csv files.

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    name=file.split(".csv")[0]
    name=pd.read_csv(path+file)
```

This creates dataframe with the name "name".
I want dataframes names to be "Case","PatientInfo","Policy",etc.

Comment: Best to use a dictionary and use those file names as keys to a dictionary of dataframes. IMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    name=file.split(".csv")[0]
    df=pd.read_csv(path+file)
    exec("%s = df" % (name))
```

Demonstration:

```
name = 'ali'
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
exec("%s = df" % (name))
```

Output:

```
ali

    0
0   1
1   2
2   3
```

Comment: output for every name is ' '

Comment: Yes. The problem is solved.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

this should help create the dataframes...

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    name=file.split(".csv")[0]
    exec('{} = pd.read_csv(\'{}\')'.format(name, file))
```